# How can I implement Liquibase with scyllaDB?

Tags: cassandra, liquibase, scylla, cassandra-jdbc-driver

I tried to implement Liquibase with Apache Cassandra using the guide [Liquibase with Apache Cassandra](https://www.liquibase.com/blog/running-liquibase-apache-cassandra). The guide was well-explained, and I was able to successfully implement the example.

However, since I am new to ScyllaDB and Liquibase, I am now trying to implement Liquibase with ScyllaDB. Unfortunately, I have not been able to find a guide on how to do this.

I learned from the above **Liquibase with Apache Cassandra** example that we need two JAR files - **a JDBC driver** and **a Liquibase extension**, but I'm unable to find them.

Can somebody please help me with this task? Any small help would be greatly appreciated, as it would resolve a big problem for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the same setup that you have for Cassandra, but point it to your ScyllaDB via the jdbc URL as if it was a Cassandra database. Because ScyllaDB claims Cassandra compatibility. So, you'd change the hostname, port, and database but leave the prefix as "cassandra".

If you are ambitious, you could implement a Liquibase extension for ScyllaDB. Check out the docs here on how to do that: https://contribute.liquibase.com/extensions-integrations/extension-guides/add-a-database/

Answer (score 0):

The Cassandra JDBC driver from Simba (now Magnitude Software) referenced in [the procedure you linked](https://www.liquibase.com/blog/running-liquibase-apache-cassandra) cannot be used with Scylla DB.

The license terms specifies that the Cassandra JDBC driver can only be used with:

- open-source [Apache Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/)
- [DataStax Enterprise](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise)
- DataStax's managed Cassandra-as-a-service [Astra DB](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-astra)

The Simba drivers are proprietary software, not open-source, so their usage is bound by rules and conditions. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the response , can you guide me Which drivers for scylladb should i used to achieve my task ?

Comment: I don't think they have a JDBC driver. Hopefully someone from Scylla will respond to your question. Cheers!